# Why can everyone edit questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

Some of the questions that I have asked on Stack Overflow have been edited by other users. As the original author, I have no control over who edits the questions and whether the edit should be published or not.

Sometimes, after multiple edits the question becomes too generic or too far away from the original intention behind asking the question. Shouldn't there be an approval system where the author should approve an edit before it updates the question or answer?

Comment: This has been discussed at some length on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I were allowed to place bets on this, I would assume you are talking about [Facebook RSS Feeds Has Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28204978/359284), a question which I made an edit to earlier.

Everyone on Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange websites) can suggest or make edits to questions and answers. If the user making the edit has less than 2000 reputation, their edits are placed in an edit queue to be peer reviewed by others. You can find more information about it at the help page titled ["Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

---

Now, I specifically made [the edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28204978/3) because it showed up a close vote audit, [which I failed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7127199). I feel that the question, as it stood before, was not well suited for Stack Overflow as it revolved around Facebook deprecating a feature *on schedule*. That's not something that Stack Overflow, or most of the contributors, have control over.

But you did have a pretty good answer to your question: a solution to what I feel was the actual problem, and probably the one thing saving that question in the long run. **As it originally was phrased, the best answer to your question was "you should have watched the changelog"**, but in reality **your question was looking for an answer to "what can I do to work around this?"**. This is what your answer covered, and it's what future visitors to your question would also be trying to solve. I tried my best to reword your question to both *complain about the API deprecation*, and *ask how to best work around it*.

Answer (score 4):

This is answered in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) on editing.

> **Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?**
>
> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!
>
> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

---

To answer your question about approvals: There is a review process. As the original poster, you can reject (or rollback) any edit that is done to your post. On top of that, *other* users can also rollback changes that are not appropriate. Users without 2000 reputation also need the community to review their edit suggestions. The community can reject these edits as well.

> **What happens if someone suggests a bad edit?**
>
> If a user without edit privileges proposes an edit that does not comply with the guidelines above, it is ordinarily rejected in the review process. Even if a bad edit is applied to a post, other users will generally fix it. Users with sufficient reputation may elect to roll back the post to a previous version (by viewing the revision history of the post and selecting the version they would like to display).

Comment: Also note that as the OP, you will be notified if your post is edited, and if that edit is a suggested edit, you will be sent to a review queue where you can take a binding action on a post if you get there before three reviewers have.